# Core Data datatypes and lists

Tags: ios, core-data

I am new to Core Data and am in the process of integrating it into an existing iPhone application. Here is my question:

Along with the standard data types available for entity attributes, is there any way to store multiple values for an attribute, such as a list? Or can I create some custom list class and have it available as an attribute data type?

Thanks, Viv!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a list type attribute, of other records to store in core data, you can use a too many relationship. Otherwise, if you just want a custom style attribute, it is possible to wrap any class inside of an NSData object and then store it as a Binary Data Attribute. This being said, you will not be able to use a fetch request to search the database using properties of this data, just whether or not it exists.

Answer (score 2):

> Along with the standard data types available for entity attributes, is
>   there any way to store multiple values for an attribute, such as a
>   list?

If you have multiple values to store for a single property, make a separate entity that holds one instance of such a value and use a [to-many relationship](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-185436-TPXREF147).